# Mixture of density functions

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Can Mathematica select the appropriate number of terms when fitting a density function with a mixture of density functions? If so, can it also select the most suitable distributions involved in the mixture?

Comment: I think you need to supply more information.  Do you have a definition of "appropriate" ?  Is there some reason why using `SmoothHistogram` or `SmoothKernelDistribution` won't meet your objective?  Is your sample size large or small?

Comment: Thanks JimB. I would require a functional representation of the density function. The sample size would be >50. Appropriate means a sufficient number of components to provide an accurate approximation.

Comment: If you have an automatic estimation procedure, then *Mathematica* can certainly fit it.  But first you need the automatic procedure (which I don't think exists) so asking this question (leaving out the need to use *Mathematica*) at stats.stackexchange.com might be more helpful.  Then back here if an appropriate answer arises.